# php metodo post

Tags: php, post

tengo un formulario en un intento de php con el campo fecha

```
<form action="../control/registrar_factura.php" method="POST">
        <h3>Ingrese los datos</h3>
<!-------Tabla DATOS----------------------------------->

            Datos facturacion

                <label id="etiqueta" for="id_factura">Numero de Factura:</label>
                <?php $query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM facturas");
                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $valor=$valores['id_factura'];
                    $actual = $valor+1;?>
                    <input type="text" id="id_factura" name="id_factura" class="cajas" value="<?php echo $actual;}?>" disabled>

                <label id="etiqueta" for="id_usuario">Usuario Factura:</label>
                <input type="text" class="cajas" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nombreusuario'] . " " . $_SESSION['apellidousuario']?>"disabled>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>" name="id_usuario"/>

                <label id="etiqueta" for="fecha">Fecha de Facturacion:</label>
                <?php $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); echo '<input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha" class="cajas" value="'.$fecha.'" disabled>';?>
```

Pero cuando presiono el boton no llegan los campos a donde necesito y me bota error de index, esta es la pagina que procesa los datos

```
    <?php
    include '../control/conexion.php';
    $result = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM facturas");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { foreach ($row as $key =>          $val) { echo "<td>" .$key. ': ' . $val . "</td>"; } echo ''; }

    $id = $_POST['id_factura'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    echo $id;
    echo $fecha;

    $query = "INSERT INTO facturas (fecha, id_usuario, id_cliente,      id_serv_1, id_serv_2, id_serv_3, id_producto_1, cant_facturada_1,  valor_total_1, id_producto_2, cant_facturada_2, valor_total_2, id_producto_3, cant_facturada_3, valor_total_3, id_producto_4, cant_facturada_4, valor_total_4, id_producto_5, cant_facturada_5, valor_total_5, total_factura)  VALUES ('$_POST[fecha]', '$_POST[id_usuario]', '$_POST[id_cliente]', '$_POST[id_servicio]', '$_POST[id_servicio1]', '$_POST[id_servicio2]', '$_POST[id_prod]', '$_POST[cant_factu]', '$_POST[valor_total]', '$_POST[id_prod1]', '$_POST[cant_facturada1]', '$_POST[valor_total1]', '$_POST[id_prod2]', '$_POST[cant_facturada2]', '$_POST[valor_total2]', '$_POST[id_prod3]', '$_POST[cant_facturada3]', '$_POST[valor_total3]', '$_POST[id_prod4]', '$_POST[cant_facturada4]', '$_POST[valor_total4]', '$_POST[total_factura]')";
if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script> var r = confirm('Factura: ".$_POST['id_factura']." Registrada Exitosamente!....registrar nueva factura?');
        if (r == true) {
            window.location.href='../vista/generar_factura.php';
            } else {
                window.location.href='../vista/panel_control.php';
                }
          </script>";
} else  {
    echo $conexion->error;
    echo "<script>alert('Error al registrar la factura.'); window.location.href='../vista/panel_control.php';</script>";
        }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
```

No tengo ni idea que estoy haciendo mal
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los campos Disabled no se mandan.

Si muestras un var_dump de $_POST comprobarás que el campo fecha no llega.

En su lugar usa readonly.

Comment: No puedo creer que sea un error tan basico, muchas gracias los cambie y ya funciona